# Disable power LED blinks during Vista hybrid sleep?

Tags: windows-vista, sleep, led

Does anyone know how to disable the blinking power LED when Vista enters hybrid sleep mode?  My case has a very bright blue LED that is rather distracting.  I'd rather not disable hybrid sleep, as it works perfectly and allows for much faster resumes than restoring from a hibernated state.

Comment: The bright blue led illuminates my entire room at night; I know exactly what you're talking about!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can't. The blinking is controlled by the motherboard, not control by the OS.

You can try to put some tape to cover the LED or unplug the LED light from the power supply though.

Comment: I ended up unplugging the power LED.  Not my first choice, but it solved the problem.

Comment: Good to know. That's what I did to my case also, the blue LED was too bright.

Answer (score 3):

Well, to add theoretical hardware solutions: if the LED is too bright, adding a simple resistor will do the trick. A somewhat neater if more speculative hack would be to add a [passive low-pass filter](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_2.html) which is nothing but a resistor and a capacitor. If you get it right, it would turn your blinking LED into a pulsing LED which is maybe less distracting and might look better. However, LEDs don't have a linear response curve, so you should prepare for the payoff not looking quite as cool as you would have liked. Also, I won't be held responsible for anyone trying this and bricking their mainboard.

Comment: I just did this and the results are beautiful! I used a 470k resistor and three 2.2uf capacitors in parallel (because I didn't have anything bigger handy).  It lights up quickly, fades out gently, and is *way* less bright.

Comment: @NathanFriedly That's amazing! Thanks for sharing the values that worked for you. Feel free to add your own answer with a picture if you think that would help others.

Comment: That's a good idea! I was thinking I wanted to clean it up a little bit, and then write a blog post about it. But I might post an answer here to, now that you mention it.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not exactly what was asked here, but since there is no software way to disable lights in sleep mode at the moment and this question is linked as duplicate for a [different one](https://superuser.com/questions/932504/how-to-stop-power-light-on-pc-from-blinking-when-in-sleep-mode) (so I can't post there), I post here what was extremely useful for me and can be useful for others:*

First of all, **I have**:

- Windows 7
- Z170-P motherboard

What **I wanted**:

- no PC light at night
- restore all applications statuses at morning, when I turn PC "on"

The asnwer was to use [S4 (hybernation) state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of sleep (S1-S3) state. I didn't know about that before, but those a different modes. The main difference is that S4 is slower than sleep, but takes less power to sustain and power LED won't blink.
[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13770/windows-shut-down-sleep-hibernate-your-pc) is how to anable this state and bind it to keyboard or power button.

Now, some lights are still on in this state. I was able to turn them off too, using [ErP option](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?52422-HOW-TO-Turning-off-All-motherboar-lights-when-shut-down-Keep-ROG-LED-when-PC-is-on): go to BIOS->Advanced->APM->ErP and switch to "Enable for P4/P5".