# How to disable LEDs on laptop Fujitsu-Siemens Amilo Pi-3525

Tags: laptop, led

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable power LED blinks during Vista hybrid sleep?](https://superuser.com/questions/45990/disable-power-led-blinks-during-vista-hybrid-sleep)

How do I completely disable the 3 annoying LEDs 'Power', 'WiFi' and 'Charging' on my laptop? They blink at me when I'm trying to sleep, I have to put objects in front of them. Small annoyance but it's getting old now.

Though if there's no nice way, there's always duct tape :)

OS is Vista.

Comment: I don't know, you could maybe just, err... *shut down* your laptop?

Comment: Um, I don't want to.

Comment: Then I'll guess you'll have to resort to duct tape. Or just put your laptop in another room.

Comment: Also: see http://superuser.com/questions/45990/disable-power-led-blinks-during-vista-hybrid-sleep

Answer (score 1):

I put [Blu-Tack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetac) on the LED's of monitors that have bright blue LEDs. Goes on easy and comes off easy.