# How to stop power light on PC from blinking when in sleep mode?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, sleep, led

I regularly put my PC into sleep mode. Unfortunately the power button LED blinks every second and it's extremely bright blue which makes sleeping in the same room somewhat challenging. I have resorted to sticking gaffer tape on top but then it becomes difficult to press the button and it leaves a nasty sticky residue on the case/button. Is there a "soft" way to disable this blinking?

This system has a ASRock X79 Extreme6 motherboard and is running Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: put masking tape over it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only two options, since the LED is controlled by the motherboard, and You can not change it with software

1. You keep using your sticking tape.
2. You unplug it from your motherboard, and configure your bios so You can power your PC from your keyboard.

EDIT: to be more accurate in my second point, I suggested disconnecting the power cable from the motherboard. See on picture:
[image]